# Remove tildes and characters from excel file in python

Tags: python, excel

I have a script in which I am auto-populating an excel file with data from another file.  The only problem is the text in the columns has tildes in it so the result is N/A.  Is there a way I can remove the tildes as well as characters in python?
An example is 12345~R3~A8987~ABC, I want to remove the tildes so I can search it as well as remove the ABC at the end

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'file1.xlsx')
wb1 = load_workbook(filename = 'file2.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws1 = wb1['Sheet1']
for row in ws1 ['AW4:AW7']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(C{0}, 'file1.xlsx'!$C:$G, 5, FALSE)".format(cell.row)
for row in ws1 ['AX4:AX7']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(D{0}, 'file1.xlsx'!$D:$H, 5, FALSE)".format(cell.row)        
wb1.save('file2.xlsx')
```

**UPDATE:**
I got this code to replace the tildes and ABC but it only prints the results (so I know the code works), but it won't actually save the excel file.

```
for row in ws1 ['C2:C7']:
for cell in row:
    remove_til = cell.value.replace(chr(126)," ").replace("ABC","")
print(remove_til)
wb1.save('REQ20200113_C.xlsx')
```

Comment: Replace/Substitute `Chr(126)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function, which replaces a target string with a replacement string:

```
 new_string = old_string.replace(target, replacement)
```

So you would add it when your read the value of a certain cell. Just replace old_string with the value you read from the cell and this code should work.

```
old_string = "12345~R3~A8987~ABC"
target = ["~", "ABC"]
replacement = [" ", ""]
tmp_string = old_string.replace(target[0],replacement[0])
new_string = tmp_string.replace(target[1],replacement[1])
print(new_string)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but it won't save the replacement when I open the actual excel file.  The output in the terminal displays the correct replacements so I know the code works.  I have the code at the end to save it but it isn't actually saving.

Comment: It doesn’t look like your writing anything to the file. I’m not exactly sure about how the openpyxl library works, but is there a way you can update the wb1 object? You’re manipulating the string properly, however you’re just not saving the results. You’re just opening the file and reading from it.